# JQuery положить в переменную текст из элементов нескольких классов

Tags: jquery, массивы, переменные

```
<div class="items selected ml-2 mr-2 mt-2">  
<img width="100px" height="80px"class="item" src="img1.jpg"> <br>
<p id="name">Текст который надо взять</p>
</div>
```

Добрый день всем, прошу вашей помощи ибо сам не могу сделать) 
Есть несколько дивов, с одинаковыми классами (selected), нужно чтобы в переменную внеслись все значения

с id = "name" которые есть в дивах с классом(selected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример, если можно использовать jQuery, но давать несколько одинаковых `id` плохая идея, т.к. id на странице задуман быть уникальным.

```js
var result = [];
$('.items.selected > p[id="name"]').each(function(index, p) {
  result.push($(p).text());
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items selected ml-2 mr-2 mt-2">
  <img width="100px" height="80px" class="item" src="img1.jpg"> <br>
  <p id="name">Текст который надо взять</p>
</div>
<div class="items selected ml-2 mr-2 mt-2">
  <img width="100px" height="80px" class="item" src="img1.jpg"> <br>
  <p id="name">Текст который надо взять 1</p>
</div>
<div class="items selected ml-2 mr-2 mt-2">
  <img width="100px" height="80px" class="item" src="img1.jpg"> <br>
  <p id="name">Текст который надо взять 2</p>
</div>
```